# Why does submit button not working for some users

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a tool in google app script and the tool is working fine. All of a sudden in the form the submit button is not working for some users.  See below code of my form:

```
<div id="confirm"></div>
<div id="myBtn">VL Applicants Count>></div>
<form id="logForm" class="form-style-1">
  <label>Request Date <span class="required">*</span></label>
  <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="LoggedDate" class="field-long" placeholder="Date of VL"
    onkeypress="return false;" />
  <label>Reason of Leave <span class="required">*</span></label>
  <textarea id="rol" name="reason" class="field-long field-textarea"></textarea>

  <input type="text" id="timeStamp" name="TimeStamp" readonly />
  <input type="text" id="tNum" name="TcktNum" readonly />

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit-form" class="login100-form-btn"
    onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(formSubmitted) .writeForm(this.parentNode); return false;" />
</form>

<script>
  function formSubmitted(status) {

    document.getElementById('confirm').innerHTML = status;
  }
</script>
```

I have updated my post and add the code needed in code.gs to run the submit button.

code.gs

```
function writeForm(form) { 

  try {  
    var email = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
    var self = ContactsApp.getContact(email);
    var TimeStamp = form.TimeStamp;
    var dovl = form.LoggedDate;
    var rovl = form.reason;
    var ldap = Session.getEffectiveUser().getUsername();
    var ReqNum = form.TcktNum;
    var stat = "Pending";
    var vltype = "Whole Day";
    var quote = '"';
    var TcktCreator = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail(); 

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1_BuyTaupXC-D-BbLEneWlEyuv2XSKm-xCCjLRi5gf1U');

    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("VL Request");
    var newRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1;//go to the first blank row
    var valLdap = 'Please complete the required Fields. <br>';
    var dateapplied = 'Date already applied<br>';
    //writes the form data to the spreadsheet
    var data = SpreadsheetApp
        .openById('1_BuyTaupXC-D-BbLEneWlEyuv2XSKm-xCCjLRi5gf1U')
        .getSheetByName("VL Request")
        .getDataRange()
        .getValues();
    var vldate = [5];
    var curruser = [2];
    for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        var vlcheckdate = data[i][vldate];
        var monthcount = vlcheckdate.getMonth()+1;
        var datecount = vlcheckdate.getDate();
      if(monthcount < 10) {
        var formattedMonth = '0' + (vlcheckdate.getMonth()+1);
      }
      else{
        var formattedMonth = (vlcheckdate.getMonth()+1);
      }

      if(datecount < 10) {
        var formattedDate = '0' + vlcheckdate.getDate();
      }
      else{
        var formattedDate = vlcheckdate.getDate();
      }


      var formattedDateVL = formattedMonth + '/' + formattedDate + '/' + vlcheckdate.getYear();

      if((formattedDateVL == dovl) && (data[i][curruser] == ldap)){
        var checker = "1";
        break;
      }
    }

    if(dovl == "" || rovl == ""){
      return valLdap; 
    }

    if(checker == "1") {
     return dateapplied; 
    }

    else{

      var data = SpreadsheetApp
        .openById('1_BuyTaupXC-D-BbLEneWlEyuv2XSKm-xCCjLRi5gf1U')
        .getSheetByName("Users")
        .getDataRange()
        .getValues();
      var user = [0];
      var lob = [4];
      var tlldap = [5];
      var tlname = [7];
      var name = [2];
      var pocldap = [11];
      var omldap = [8];
      for (var j = 1; j < data.length; j++) { 
   if (data[j][user] === ldap){
   var tlLdap = data[j][tlldap];
   var fname = data[j][name];
   var tlName = data[j][tlname];  
   var lane = data[j][lob];
   var poc = data[j][pocldap];
     var om = data[j][omldap];
   }
   }

    var range = sheet.getRange(newRow, 1);    
    range.setValue(TimeStamp);
    range = sheet.getRange(newRow, 2);
    range.setValue(ReqNum);
    range = sheet.getRange(newRow, 4);
    range.setValue(tlLdap);   
    range = sheet.getRange(newRow, 5);
    range.setValue(vltype);
    range = sheet.getRange(newRow, 6);
    range.setValue(dovl);
    range = sheet.getRange(newRow, 7);
    range.setValue(rovl);
    range = sheet.getRange(newRow, 8);
    range.setValue(fname);
    range = sheet.getRange(newRow, 9);
    range.setValue(tlName);
    range = sheet.getRange(newRow, 10);
    range.setValue(lane);  
    range = sheet.getRange(newRow, 3);
    range.setValue(ldap);
    range = sheet.getRange(newRow, 13);
    range.setValue(stat);
    range = sheet.getRange(newRow, 16);
    range.setValue(poc);
    range = sheet.getRange(newRow, 17);
    range.setValue(om);  

    }


    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var validation_file = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1_BuyTaupXC-D-BbLEneWlEyuv2XSKm-xCCjLRi5gf1U");
  var logged_act_sheet = validation_file.getSheetByName("VL Request"); 

   //an array of confirmation messages that will display as HTML 
    var confirmationMessage = ['<B>Time Stamp:</B> ' + TimeStamp +
                               '<br><B>Request ID:</B> ' + ReqNum +
                               '<br><B>Name:</B> ' + ldap +
                               "<br><B>Date of VL:</B> " + dovl + 
                               "<br><B>Reason of VL:</B> " + rovl +
                               "<br><B>Status:</B> " + stat +
                               '<br><br><B><a href="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwtc_JY2ddOs0EdOmYvJiaQWbEfKmTdzqIN4Oq4SG0/dev">Refresh page>></a><B><br><br>' 
                              ];
    var len = confirmationMessage.length-1;
    Logger.log('len= ' + len);
    var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);//randomizes from the array

    return confirmationMessage[i]; //displays randomized message

  } 

  catch (error) {

    return error.toString();
  }
}
```

I am actually thinking if there's an update from google that my script might not be able to run for some type of users.

Comment: Hi! Is your HTML form in Google Sites? Just as a quick reminder Apps Script can only be used for Google Services, for example, Google Forms, Sites, Docs and so on. [Check here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) the functionalities and scopes of Apps Script.

Comment: It's a web app using google script. Actually, it's working fine a few weeks ago. However, all of a sudden the submit button is not working for some users.

Comment: You are not using Apps Script in that HTML first because you can't use it outside of google services (in that case you would need to interact with each service API such as Google Drive's API) and second because you are not calling it in your code. **Please, provide more information like more sample code or details**

Comment: I've  updated my post and include the code from code.gs to run the script when you click the submit button. And yes this is actually running inside Google Drive of my company.

Comment: Browser console logs?

Comment: There's no error in logs, I am actually thinking if this something to do with the new V8?